# Email is not sending in django code as well as it is not giving any error in the console

Tags: python, django, sendmail

I am implementing a code to send email. However, the code is not sending the email and also it is not showing any tangible error.

views.py code:

```
@require_POST
def thanks(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST['name']
        email = request.POST['email']
        phone= request.POST['phone']
        doctor = request.POST['doctor']
        msg = request.POST['reason']
        print(name, email, phone, msg)
        appointment_db = Appointment(name=name, email=email, phone=phone, doctor=doctor, 
        message=msg)
        appointment_db.save()

    subject = "Thank you for registering"
    message = "Welcome the the clinic."
    from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
    recipient_list = [email]
    send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list)
    print("email sent")
    return render(request, "thanks.html", {"name": name})
```

In the above code, the second-last line is also not printing anything in the console.

settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND= "django.core.mail.backends.smpt.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT= 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "host email" # email from which i sent email
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "host password" #password of the host account
```

imports in views.py:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.conf import settings
```

It is basically a registration form which is sending confirmation email to the person who is attempting to register.**strong text**

Comment: You don't send the email under the `if request.method == 'POST'` clause?

Comment: still not working after puting the mail code under if request.method == 'POST'

Comment: Could you check the return value of `send_mail()`? It would be either 0 or 1, indicating the amount of successfully delivered emails (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/email/#send-mail)).

Comment: its not even executing the second-last print function